# Prevent wrapping of floated span element with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a span inside an `<h3>` that is wrapping to the next line once the text gets too long. I need the description text to all stay on the first line with the `.title` and `overflow:hidden`. The description should align right, the title should align left.

This design pattern is used throughout the application, so changing the html elements themselves is a last resort. I'd like to solve this with a simple CSS solution if possible. I've been trying every combination of `overflow`, `text-overflow`, and `white-space` that I can think of with no luck. Thanks!

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksyx5zgr/)

```css
.title {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: green;
}
.description {
  float: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
Long:
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">
    title
    <span class="description">descriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescription</span>
  </h3>
</div>

<br>

Short:
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">
    title
    <span class="description">description</span>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you floating the span? Floating elements must come *before* the elements that are supposed to float around them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `.title` to `white-space:nowrap` + `display:table`.

```
.title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table;
}
```

```css
.title {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table;
}
.description {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
Long:
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">
    title
    <span class="description">descriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescription</span>
  </h3>
</div>

<br>

Short:
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">
    title
    <span class="description">description</span>
  </h3>
</div>
```

---

**Edit 1:** if you want to hide the extra text, you can use `white-space:nowrap` + `overflow:hidden`.

```css
.title {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.description {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
Long:
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">
    title
    <span class="description">descriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescription</span>
  </h3>
</div>

<br>

Short:
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">
    title
    <span class="description">description</span>
  </h3>
</div>
```

---

**Edit 2:** if you need the short text to expand and match the long text with no hidden text, you can use `white-space:nowrap` + `display:table-row`. Note, need to adjust the markup slightly - combine the two containers into one.

```css
.title {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: green;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: table-row;
}
.description {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3 class="title">
    title
    <span class="description">descriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescriptiondescription</span>
  </h3>
  <h3 class="title">
    title
    <span class="description">description</span>
  </h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden;` will only work if the div has a set width. You can set a width on the div to be 100vw or a set px amount and then you can use your `white-space: nowrap;` and 'overflow: hidden;` together.

```
.title {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: green;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.description {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: fixed width is not an option

Comment: @Kenji using viewport units as I did in my answer will set a width, but it will still scale with the browser and be responsive. Is that still not an option?

Answer (score 0):

Pangloss put me on the right track, here is the CSS that ended up working for me.

```
.description {
  text-align: right;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:black;
}
.container {

}
.title {
  background-color:lightblue;
  color:green;
  display:flex;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```